# Error to many redirection .htaccess Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I changed my website from http to https with Lets Encrytp. Now I can't access my Magento Admin console. I read that it's because of the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Can you tell me what I have to change? I'm not quite good in Web development.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing error like, TOO MANY REDIRECTS on your Magento store, then the issue is because of your .htaccess file or your cache folder.

Place a new copy of `.htaccess` from a fresh magento package and delete the cache and session folder as well. Then refresh and it should be good.

Or another way is,

In the `core_config_data` table remove the value of `web/cookie/cookie_domain` and set `web/cookie/cookie_httponly`” to `0`. Clear the cache by removing the files in `var/cache`. Also clear the cache from Magento admin panel

Comment: Hi so I did the things above. Still doesn't work. I put a new `.htaccess` file into my Webdirectory. Also cleaned my `/var/cache` but there is no `/var/session`.
In the `core_config_data` table the were not records for `web/cookie/cookie_domain` or `web/cookie_cookie_httponly`. And I found out that this Error only occours on the Admin Panel but the Store page works.